# javascript invalid regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've the following code:

```
$.each(css, function(i, v) {
        css[i] = this.replace('{bind}', bindName, css[i]);
});
```

I want to replace all {bind}'s with the value of bindName.
To try this I gave bindName the value 'Test'.

'css' is a simple object with data.

```
var css = {
            tabs          : 'tab-{bind}',
            outerWrapper  : 'outerWrapper-{bind}',
            innerWrapper  : 'innerWrapper-{bind}-{id}-{tab}',
            subMenue      : 'subMenue-{bind}-{id}',
            subMenueItem  : 'subMenue-Item'
          };
```

In Firefox I get the error "invalid regular expression flag k" on line 68.
Line 68:

```
$.each(css, function(i, v) {
        css[i] = this.replace('{bind}', bindName, css[i]); // LINE 68
});
```

If it's necessary this is my replace funcion:

```
this.replace = function (s, r, su) {
      return su.split(s).join(r);
    }
```

There's no error in Google-Chrome but in Firefox (newest Version) - can you find the error ?

Comment: does it work if you are wrapping this into $(this) ?

Comment: dont think so - i can try, but i think it must be this - these functions are methodes of a class so i dont think i've to do $this() - but i already tried it in another way - withoud the class and just with global functions an variables and this doesnt work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
css[i] = this.replace('{bind}', bindName, css[i]);
```

to any of these:

```
css[i] = this.replace('{bind}', bindName);

css[i] = v.replace('{bind}', bindName);

css[i] = css[i].replace('{bind}', bindName);
```

The reason for the error-message is that in Firefox, `String.replace` takes an optional third argument representing regex flags (e.g. `'i'` or `'g'`); you're passing in `css[i]` for that argument, and Firefox interprets it as containing invalid flags. The reason that Chrome *doesn't* give an error-message is that it doesn't support that nonstandard feature, so it's simply ignoring that argument entirely.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just forgot that replace is an given javascript function ... i just renamed my function and it works.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure of that, but maybe your problem is that the "{" character is special in the regular expression language.
Try to escape it :

```
css[i] = this.replace('\{bind\}', bindName, css[i]);
```